# How to prove this property of a lie group

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

The following question was part of my lecture notes on manifolds and i am struck on it.

> Suppose G is a smooth manifold with a group structure such that the map $G \times G \to G $ given by $(g, h) \to gh^{-1}$ is smooth. Prove that G is a lie group.

I have only issue in proving following: Assuming $x, y \in G$ proving  that $ (x, y) \to xy $  is smooth.

Can you please help?

Comment: Note that $gh = g(h^{-1})^{-1}$. So multiplication is the composition of the map $(x,y) \mapsto xy^{-1}$ with the inversion map in the second coordinate. Since you know both of these maps are smooth, so is multiplication.

Comment: @AustinShiner Thanks !